# Запуск нескольких процессов PHP

Tags: php

Доброго. Прошу вникнуть в вопрос

PHP, в 10 параллельных потоков выполняю определенные действия. 10, т.к. хостинг одновременно больше не держит. Ест-но, часть скриптов заканчивает работать раньше, часть позже. А задачки еще есть, и запускаю вторые десять, после того как отработают все из первого десятка. Что есть не оптимально

Вопрос, как обычно прост. Может кто объяснить, или напугать кодом, иль ссылкой, как оптимально запустить несколько скриптов на PHP, с параллельным выполнением, что бы при отработке одного включался другой из очереди?

Comment: на хостинге не установлен Redis? База данных?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так вы правильно сами же и написали – при отработке одно должен включаться следующий из очереди.

Как организовать очередь? По-хорошему, напр., сервером задач [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), но в условиях ограничений хостинга это под вопросом. Тогда какой-нибудь текстовый файл или БД.

«Рабочие» php скрипты должны крутиться постоянно. Лучше не один php скрипт постоянно, а иногда его перезапускать, чтобы не было утечек памяти. Постоянно может крутиться какой-нибудь bash скрипт, который берёт очередную задачу и запускает очередной процесс php с ней.

Чуть подробнее расскажите об ограничениях хостера и вашей задаче.

Comment: скрипт movie.php надо выполнить XXXXX раз, на моем хостинге, оптимальная работа на 10 одновременно исполняемых копиях скрипта. я запускаю их в цикле, по 10 штук за раз, и получается, что какой то отработает быстрей, какой то медленнее. код example конечно в гугле найти невозможно, что бы скачать и поюзать рабочий примерчик. 9 копий скрипта работает 1 секунду, а одна 10. т.е. если пустить параллельно 10 процессов, все выполнятся за 10 секунд, а в это время общую очередь можно не хило подвинуть. пацаны на всяких node.js таких проблем не знают, а вот на php приходиться изобретать велосипед

Comment: там что-то curl'ом тянется из внешних url? Смотрели (кстати) на [`curl_multi_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-exec.php) – можно N веб-запросов из одного php процесса запустить – но тут уж придётся ждать, пока все отработают.

Comment: вот сейчас именно так. и хочу это исправить, только не понимаю как